# How to access same table from different locations

Tags: asp.net, sql-server-2008, c#-4.0

I am having small doubt in my module. Kindly give idea regarding

this.
i.e. I have one centralized sqlserver database. This database is

accessed from all over the world.
     assume that two users are there (one user from usa & one user from india) with their own credentials.

-> if first user access one table from database & he opened 5 fields of the particular table.
-> meanwhile second user also access the same table, it will display all the fields whatever first user opened.(it reflects on the second user session)

how i can achieve this functionality? (I am developing this web application using Asp.net, C# & sqlserver 2008R2 as backend)

Comment: It's not clear what you are asking. What do you mean by "he opened 5 fields"?

Comment: Are you saying that the second user sees the results of the first user's request?

Comment: Please be specific about your question. what you are doing with your database inserting,updating or retrieving?

Comment: I don't understand your question, but you might want to research "optimistic and pessimistic concurrency" for general ideas about managing data that multiple users work on at the same time.